# Can your ISP tell what google account searched what? And can they share this information?

Tags: isp

If you search something, can your isp share the google account it was searched from?

Comment: It is Google that spies on you more than your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses HTTPS, which means traffic to / from Google is encrypted on transit.

Thanks to that encryption, your ISP can't read anything in the traffic: neither the search terms nor the Google account.

Answer (score 0):

> If you search something, can your isp share the google account it was searched from?

Your connection to Google runs exclusively via HTTPS, meaning that all the content is encrypted, but metadata isn't.

In this case, this means that your ISP can't see what account you connected from, or what you searched. This is part of the data that is encrypted.

What they can see, however, is the metadata. That means the fact that you connected to Google, and which websites you connect to afterwards.

In order to actually see what you have been searching, or which account you used to search, they would need to perform a Man-in-the-Middle attack. And as ISP, they are in the perfect position to do so, as [has been shown in 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhstan_man-in-the-middle_attack).

HTTPS is designed to notify you that somebody is attempting to attack your connection, but it's technically very difficult to protect against it. In general, I would not worry about this scenario too much. In an ISP were to spy on people, it would be rather visible, and it would make very bad press quickly.

Comment: Perhaps that's [exactly what they do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhstan_man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: @MechMK1 i know,They made users install root CA.Normal ISP don't do that

Comment: That's not what the question is about. The question is if *my* ISP can do that, and if I happen to be from Kazakhstan, then the answer is absolutely a yes. It's mainly for the sake of completion, because your phrasing makes it sound as if an ISP would not be able to circumvent encryption.

Comment: @MechMK1 but he didn't say any of that and i told him they will have to break ssl .I dont see why kazakhistan need's to be specified.

Comment: @MechMK1 gimme an edit?

Comment: Feel free to roll back. Just a suggestion

Comment: @MechMK1 nah.Its better than mine

Comment: @yeah_well, I am definitely disagreeing with people here. I have a friend that runs a lot of ads on his site as a way to make money, when I use Opera VPN, those ads are gone. Also, when I have shopped without a VPN, everyone in my household gets to see what I purchased because they start to see ads about it and vice versa. When I buy stuff with Opera VPN, that nonsense stops. Explain this to me please, two different topics at play here, maybe?

Comment: @Daniel google probably has enough data on you,to create a clear picture if traffic is coming from one household,and they have a very large ad network which your friend uses.